# Creating a directed acyclic graph in haskell with lists and sets

Tags: haskell, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I want to create a DAG in haskell but since I'm new to the whole functional programming thing I would like some directions.

The graph needs to be built with only lists and sets, and the following functions must be implemented:

v = add_vertex(g,w)

A vertex with the specified weight w is added to the DAG g and its unique vertex identifier v is returned.

add_edge(g,a,b,w)

An edge from the vertex with vertex identifier a to the vertex with vertex identifier b is added to the DAG g with weight w.

What I've done so far is creating a data type which looks like this:

```
data Graph v w = Graph {vertices :: [(v, w)],
edges :: [([(v, w)], [(v, w)], w)]} deriving Show
```

And I guess I need some form of constructor for the graph, it looks like this:

```
create_graph :: (v,w) -> w -> Graph v w 
create_graph v w  = Graph [v] [(v, v, w)]
```

What I would like to do is to create just an empty graph, but now I need to input some starting values if I understand correctly. How can I fix that?

The add_vertex function looks like this:

```
add_vertex :: Graph v w -> (v, w) -> Graph v w
add_vertex (Graph v w) x = Graph (v ++ [x]) w
```

But I dont really know how to return a vertex identifier instead of the whole graph. I guess I should also specify that the identifier needs to be a char and the weights can be either floats or ints, where do I do that?

I would also like to have functions for topological ordering and getting the weight for the longest path. With this in mind, should I define the structure of the graph in a different way?

Thanks

Comment: 1) Your graph datatype stores only vertices, but your "graph constructor" tries to store edges too. 2) Your add_vertex implementation is very uniffective. You should use : instead of ++ here. Probably you should start with less complicated exercises.

Comment: Yes, thats the problem with the constructor. I just want to make an empty graph, not inserting any vertices nor edges, is that doable? Will look into changing from ++ to :, thanks for pointing that out. Well this is the first excerise we got at school and I'm trying to read up on "learn you a haskell" as much as possible.

Comment: An empty graph would just be `emptyGraph = Graph [] []`. In your datatype, I don't understand why each edge takes two lists of vertices; and assuming that `w` is a type parameter for the weight, why the weights of the vertices are repeated in the edges.

Comment: Oh I see, still getting used to haskell syntax... Well there shouldn't be lists of vertices ofcourse. I'll change it so that edges consists of two vertex identifiers and one edge weight and I'll later map those identifiers to the list with vertices and their weights. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

what I would do is define the graph like a tree

```
data Graph a = Graph [(a,[a])] -- Graph is a list of origins paired with edgeends

createGraph ::Eq a => [(a,a)] -> Graph a
createGraph = undefined

empty :: Graph a
empty = Graph []

insertVertex :: Eq a => a -> Graph a -> Graph a
insertVertex = undefined -- insert if not already in the Graph (with empty edges)

insertEdge :: Eq a => (a,a) -> Graph a -> Graph a
insertEdge = undefined -- insert edge in list of origin
--do not forget to add origin, end if they don't exist
```

implement these and worry about bfs/topsort later and think about the result of a bfs - what do you want as a result? (the result of topsort should be a list i guess).